# PHPmailer inline .png attaching as .txt

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm adding some inline images to an email where the image is a png stored as a string.

```
$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage($imageData, $imageName);
```

and in the template

```
<img src="cid:<?= $imageName ?>" alt="">
```

The images get displayed in the received email just fine, but they also appear as attached text files.

[image]

Is there anyway to hide the attachments or at least give them meaningful file names?

Comment: Try using :
`$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('.$imageName.');`

Comment: @HayderAbbass Thanks, but  `$mail->addEmbeddedImage()` expects a filename but my image data is stored in `$imageData` as a `String`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="cid:<?= $imageName ?>" alt="">
```

should be

```
<img src="<?= $imageName ?>" alt="">
```

phpmail deals with the *cid* for you.

Comment: I tried it but now the images just get sent as attachments, they don't get embedded into the email body

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

Even when embedding images into the email body you can still specify a file name.
Its the 3rd parameter of `addStringEmbeddedImage`

```
$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage($imageData, $imageName,$imageName.'.png');
```

Comment: @Synchro I probably will if no better answer is posted but Stackoverflow makes you wait for 2 days before you can accept your own answer